# Carrierwave-video "Process hung" error while encoding uncompressed video files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have an API for a mobile app that accepts video uploads. This app is for both iOS and Android devices, so for video compatibility's sake these videos are encoded to H.264 once uploaded to the server using carrierwave-video (ffmpeg wrapper gem for Ruby on Rails). Right now this seems to be working, and videos are uploaded and encoded and can be played in both Android and iOS devices. However, sometimes the process hangs while encoding heavy ([uncompressed](https://superuser.com/questions/250155/ffmpeg-hangs-when-creating-a-video)?) video files, usually ~10+ seconds long. This is the output of ffmpeg:

```
Failed to transcode with FFmpeg.
Check ffmpeg install and verify video is not corrupt or cut short.
Original error: Process hung. Full output:
```

(That's it, the full output seems empty.)

These are the encoding parameters I'm using in my Carrierwave Uploader:

```
encode_video(:mp4, custom: '-y -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -vpre ultrafast 2> /home/user/log/ffmpeg.log, resolution: '640x640')
```

According to the SuperUser question I linked above a solution would be to encode the video twice, once to AVI for compression(?) and then encode to MP4. I don't know if that would work, but I don't know how to do this either in my uploader. I would have to encode the output video file of my first (AVI) encoding process.

Now that there's some context, my question is: How can I solve this "Process hung" error?

In case the answer to that is to go with this double encoding method suggested, how can I achieve this using Carrierwave-video?

One last note is that if I try to encode these videos using `ffmpeg` straight from command-line the videos encode and playback successfully.

Thank you for your time!

PD: Wasn't sure if I should add ruby-on-rails tag. I'll remove it if necessary!

**Edit**
This is what I get from `ffmpeg -i filename.mp4`

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 30 2013 11:26:53 with gcc 4.5.4
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --cc=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc --cxx=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ --ar=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar --optflags='-O2 -march=athlon64 -pipe' --extra-cflags='-O2 -march=athlon64 -pipe' --extra-cxxflags='-O2 -march=athlon64 -pipe' --disable-static --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --disable-stripping --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-ffplay --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaacplus --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=v4l --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=alsa --disable-indev=oss --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=alsa --disable-outdev=oss --disable-outdev=sdl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libvpx --enable-libope  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/user/api/uploads/tmp/e54zfghzt9.mp4':


Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2014-04-23 14:56:19
  Duration: 00:00:14.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20757 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 20993 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc


Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-23 14:56:19
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 190 kb/s


Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-23 14:56:19
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Then it just starts buffering as such:

```
time=00:00:13.20 bitrate=2533.2kbits/s    
frame=  405 fps=  7 q=24.0 size=    4083kB time=00:00:13.20 bitrate=2533.2kbits/s    
frame=  407 fps=  7 q=24.0 size=    4083kB time=00:00:13.20 bitrate=2533.2kbits/s    
frame=  409 fps=  7 q=24.0 size=    4083kB time=00:00:13.20 bitrate=2533.2kbits/s    
frame=  412 fps=  7 q=24.0 size=    4083kB time=00:00:13.20 bitrate=2533.2kbits/s    
frame=  417 fps=  7 q=24.0 size=    4083kB time=00:00:13.20 bitrate=2533.2kbits/s    
frame=  417 fps=  7 q=24.0 Lsize=    4194kB time=00:00:13.90 bitrate=2471.5kbits/s    
video:3957kB audio:223kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.310939%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.50  size: 25120
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] frame P:415   Avg QP:25.32  size:  9642
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] mb I  I16..4: 35.8%  0.0% 64.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] mb P  I16..4:  8.4%  0.0%  3.2%  P16..4: 43.6% 19.0%  5.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:20.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 45.2% 53.6% 27.3% inter: 39.4% 27.6% 2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] i16 v,h,dc,p: 28% 57% 11%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 66% 11%  1%  1%  1%  2%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] i8c dc,h,v,p: 23% 58% 17%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f28327ccc50] kb/s:2331.88
```

`

Comment: Neiter iOS or Android are even capable of recording raw video as far as I know.  I don't think that's your problem.  Just what **are** your input formats and codecs?  `ffmpeg -i filename` with nothing else to find out.  There isn't enough information here to help you, other than to suggest trying a different (not necessarily newer) version of FFmpeg.  Also, go and get the real STDERR output from FFmpeg.  I'm not familiar with the gem you're using... but if it's executing FFmpeg directly instead of as a library (which is implied by it being a process), you should have more output somewhere.

Comment: There! I added them. Is that the log you were asking for?

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's RAW video or not. I'm using an HTC One and ~6-second long videos are uploading properly. However when I record a 12-second video, for example, I start experiencing this error here. This 12-second video can be around ~30 MB which is why I think it could be uncompressed (heavy file size), but I honestly don't know for sure. Any guidance is appreciated, as I'm just trying to learn! Thank you, Brad.

Comment: Yes, thanks for posting those logs.  30MB is nothing for video.  30 seconds of uncompressed video at 1080p is 2.6GB.  FFmpeg is telling you that the video is already h.264, and the audio is in AAC.  In this case, there is nothing to convert.  If you wanted to convert to a different container format, you could simply use `-vcodec copy` and no re-encoding will be done, causing it to run **much** faster.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I'll give it a try and come back with the results!

Comment: That was exactly it, Brad. Thank you. I know what to do to solve my problem now. I'll verify if it's encoded in H.264 first, and if it's not then I'll try to encode it, if it already is H.264, then I'll leave it as it is. Cheers!